# Child template isn't rendering

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a layout template and a child template.  However, none of the extra information from the child template is showing up.  Why isn't the information in the child template being used?

FlaskTest.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return render_template('layout.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

layout.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    {% block head %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %} - My Webpage</title>
    {% endblock %}
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">{% block content %}{% endblock %}</div>
    <div id="footer">
      {% block footer %}
      &copy; Copyright 2010 by <a href="http://domain.invalid/">you</a>.
      {% endblock %}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

child.html

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% block title %}Index{% endblock %}

{% block head %}
    {{ super() }}
    <style type="text/css">
        .important {
            color: #336699;
        }
    </style>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Index</h1>
    <p class="important">
        Welcome on my awesome homepage.
{% endblock %}
```

On `http://localhost:5000/` I get:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css">
    <title> - My Webpage</title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="footer">

      &copy; Copyright 2010 by <a href="http://domain.invalid/">you</a>.

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to render child.html, not layout.html.  Child will *extend* layout, but the way you've written it, only layout will be rendered.

```
return render_template('child.html')
```